# What is the optimal way to get only latest ID's from table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get only a single row per Appointment Number in a table storing a history of appointments.  It works fine with a few rows but then gets slower?  Is this the best way to do this kind of check and I'm just missing some indexes or is there a better way?

```
DECLARE @temptable TABLE
    (
        id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
      , ApptNumber INT NOT NULL
      , ApptDate DATE NOT NULL
      , Notes VARCHAR(50) NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES (1,1,'01-DEC-2018','First Appointment')
INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES (2,1,'01-DEC-2018','')
INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES (3,1,'01-DEC-2018','Rescheduled')
INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES (4,2,'02-DEC-2018','Second Appointment')
INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES (5,2,'02-DEC-2018','Cancelled')
INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES (6,3,'03-DEC-2018','Third Appointment')
INSERT INTO @temptable VALUES (7,4,'04-DEC-2018','Fourth Appointment')

SELECT * FROM @temptable
SELECT MAX(id) FROM @temptable GROUP BY ApptNumber

SELECT tt.* FROM @temptable tt
INNER JOIN  (SELECT MAX(id) [Id] FROM @temptable GROUP BY ApptNumber) appts ON appts.Id = tt.id
```

Comment: Why not just `SELECT TOP 1...`?

Comment: I want 4 rows returned- the "max" of Appt 1, 2, 3 and 4

Comment: The standard approach to this would be using a ROW_NUMBER() window function. e.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ApptNumber ORDER BY id DESC) FROM @temptable) AS T WHERE RN = 1`, but as far as performance goes, if it's going very slowly you probably need an index on apptnumber, id desc (and if you're selecting all columns, probably need to include the others to avoid a key lookup)... e.g. `create index ix_temptable_apptnumber_id on temptable (apptnumber, id desc) include (apptdate, notes)` or something like that.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on an identity column having any meaning, including the concept that higher values are newer. A whole host of factors can break that. Use ROW_NUMBER, and order by an InsertedDatetime column rather than ID... And, as you hinted at, make sure you have the right indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
select * from (
    SELECT f1.*, row_number() over(partition by ApptNumber order by id desc ) rang FROM @temptable f1
) tmp where rang=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2:

```
with tmp as (
select ApptNumber, max(ID) MaxID
from @temptable
group by ApptNumber
)
select f1.* from @temptable f1 inner join tmp f2 on f1.ID=f2.MaxID
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 3:

```
select distinct f3.* from @temptable f1 
cross apply
(
 select top 1 * from @temptable f2
 where f1.ApptNumber=f2.ApptNumber
 order by f2.ID desc

) f3
```

Answer (score -1):

Window function

```
SELECT tt.* 
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by ApptNumber order by id desc) as rn 
) tt
where tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: should it not be `(partition by ApptNumber order by id desc)` instead of `over by`?